# Ubuntu worldtime desktop clock widget?

Tags: 12.04, unity

I am aware that in Unity we can add world time by clicking on time bar. However, it's still a list of locations and sometimes it may be hard to quickly find the timezone of interest.

Is there any tool which can put a multiple clock instances on the desktop representing each timezone of interest? Similar to the clock in Windows 7.

To be more clear, I am **not looking for a weather widget**, but a simple clock widget so that I can track time in different timezones.

Comment: Did u get any solution?

Comment: @RoyMJ Nope. There is no such widget it seems. Until it appears I am using the builtin timeclock

Comment: hmm...:(...do follow up if you find anything good